# Kentio UI Permissions on an AD Role

Tags: kentico

I've been working with the UI Permissions to lock down the site for certain editor types. I have it working with a role i created. If i was to update the UI Permissions on an domain role, is there a risk of these permissions being lost if any changes are made on the domain controller?

Answer (score 1):

If the domain role is deleted yes you can lose the settings, however i don't think the kentico ad sync tool deletes ad groups, just adds and updates (i could be wrong though).

To be extra safe thought, you can hook into the global kentico events and catch when a user is assigned a role to see if the role is an ad role and assign also then to a non ad role, but you will need to also catch removal from ad role to remove from the non ad role. I did this myself for a client.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AD Import utility then it's possible to choose whether to [Delete users and roles that do not exist in the Active Directory](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Importing+users+and+roles+from+Active+Directory#ImportingusersandrolesfromActiveDirectory-Step4%E2%80%93Importsettings). It only considers roles with `IsDomain=1` - those that were imported from AD. You don't have to worry about non-AD roles.

If you're using the open-source [AD Import service](https://github.com/Kentico/ADImportService) then roles get always deleted when they're deleted from AD.

Comment: We 're not using the AD Import at this point. I think for now, i'll work with Kentico roles, get this working, then explore using an domain role.

Comment: I'd say a rule of thumb would be to separate concerns - use one set of roles for security and another for UI permissions. You can then decide which roles should be synced from AD. Certainly the security ones but you could also have the UIP ones in AD. That's up to you. Consider who's going to maintain what and how often will it change.